# Routing issue with complex segments

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

My application performs a search of items by location.
I have a few custom routes and redirect rules to provide a nice and friendly URL to the user but I just noticed a strange behaviour with some of them.

My route is defined as follow:

```
routes.MapRoute("searchRoute", "search/in-{location}", new { controller = "search", action = "index" });
```

The following searches work very well:

- /search/in-melbourne
- /search/in-western-australia
- /search/in-sydney-NSW
- /search/in-perth-WA-6000
- /search/in-brisbane-CBD
- /search/in-australian-capital-territory-act

The complex pattern I use here is "**search/in-{location}**". I also format the location by replacing any white space characters by a '-' with some redirects elsewhere (but it is not relevant here).. 
The problem happens when the search URL has a location that contains "**in-**":

For instance, the URLs **/search/in-darwin-city** or **/search/in-testin-test** are not matched by my searchRoute (I used RouteDebugger to confirm it and even tested other keyword than 'in-' without luck).

Microsoft doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#complex-segments) says:

> Complex segments (for example **[Route("/x{token}y")]**) are processed by
>   matching up literals from right to left in a non-greedy way.

I had a look at the code (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Http/Routing/src/Patterns/RoutePatternMatcher.cs#L293) but still not sure why this is happening and most importantly how to solve that.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: your tag is `ASP.Net MVC`, but your docs links are for `ASP.Net Core MVC`. Are you on `.Net Core` or `.Net Framework`?

Comment: I use both with two different apps having the same problem. I don't believe the .NET version (4.5 or Core 2.2) is relevant as the routing engine seems to be the same.

Comment: Not sure by routing engine, but in general `ASP.Net Core MVC` is an almost completely rewritten version of `ASP.Net MVC` - they shouldn't be expected to behave the same. Also by _"Are you on .Net Core or .Net Framework?"_ I really mean "Are you on `ASP.Net Core MVC`  or on classic `ASP.Net MVC`?", sorry for misleading?

Comment: You may also try to use `"search/in-{*location}"` (this should make it greedy), but I'm not sure how it will handle **/search/in-testin-test/something?query=data**

Answer (score 1):

it won't match because the matching process confuses the position
of the literal content with the first part of the content that should be assigned to the location variable since the matching is done from right to left.
so let's say your URL is "/search/in-darwin-city".
what is at the end? "in-city" so the location variable is assumed to be equal to "city" but what remains is "search/in-darw" which is not equal to "search/" so it's not a match.

if you do something like this: "/search/in-darwincity" and set the route to "/search/in-{location}" then the location variable is going to be "darwincity" and everything works.